# Angular - Adding -js fle getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Tags: javascript, angular, sass

I have an angular 6 app, I'm trying to setup my own style library...
This is how looks `angular.json` file:

```
"root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "prefix": "app",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  },
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/adm-auth-frontend",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "src/assets/scripts/index.js"
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
```

As you can see, the project was setup with sass and its working good.
The problem is that I need some scripts files, I've added those files on the scripts sections but when I run execute **ng serve** get the following error and still now working :(

[See error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vYI7.png)

I've tried to add it on `webpack` config file by using `ng eject` but..

```
The `eject` command has been temporarily disabled, as it is not yet compatible with the new `angular.json` format. The new configuration format provides further flexibility to modify the configuration of your workspace without ejecting. Ejection will be re-enabled in a future release of the CLI.If you need to eject today, use CLI 1.7 to eject your project.
```

**index.js** file:

```
@import './spec/settings/index.scss';
@import './spec/tools/index.scss';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import './spec/index.scss';
@import './vendor/index.scss';
```

How can I add these `.js` files?

Answer (score 0):

Angular scripts added on angular.json file are run only once
when angular took over the application it will read those scripts once and loaded
so it is not recommend to use js files with angular cus they are not functioning again unless manually re-triggered upon change to the HTML.

instead use typescript libraries like ng-bootstrap or
Temporary solution is add manual tag  on index.html, 
this worked but isn't good enough.